# incorrect syntax command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, syntax

i'm new to the coding of batch files and got an error wich i can not solve..
the problem occurs at the :secName , I made a printscreen at the flash(just before it exits cmd), and it said: "so your name is [what %name% is]"and then "the syntax of the command is incorrect.
goto was unexpected at this time."
i've got this coding done now:

```
@echo off
goto Welcome
title The Game Of Everything

:welcome
echo.
echo Welcome!
echo What is your name?
set /p name=Enter: 
goto secName


:secName
cls
echo.
echo so your name is %name%?
set /p secName:yes or no?:
if %secName%== yes goto begin 
if %secName%==no goto welcome

:begin
cls
echo.
echo Welcome %name%, to "The Game Of Everything"!
echo I hope you enjoy this mini-game, downloadable on your computer!
echo.
echo It isn't the prettiest, but who gives a toss right?







echo press any key to continue...
pause>nul

exit
```

Comment: `set /p secName=yes or no?:` and correct the space in the next line

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
set /p secName:yes or no?:
```

to this

```
set /p secName=yes or no?:
```